# Fullcalendar v4: prev button and browser back button integration fail

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, html5-history, fullcalendar-4

I am using Fullcalendar v4 and am trying to hook up browser forward/back buttons into FC navigation.  I have an issue when trying to use the browser buttons after clicking the `prev` FC button in the month display.

I tried creating a fiddle and using codepen but I think the wrappers those sites use interfere with some aspect of the browser button events.  I have setup a pruned down sample at  [HERE](https://test.pipers-hut.com/index.html)

An example of expected behavior is:

- Visit the link above; click the `Go to calendar` link (for testing I need a launch page to test the back button operation from the real calendar "home" page).
- Look at the top, right of the calendar toolbar and click the month then day buttons in turn.
- Use the browser back/forward buttons to move between the views.

An example of the flawed behavior:

- Go the the month view.  Look to the top, left of the calendar toolbar and click the "<" `prev` button.  This will move the display back one month.
- Try to use the browser back button to return to the initial month view and nothing happens.

I am managing the calendar state via `window.history.state`.  It looks to me that when a page is first visited the `window.history.state` is null.  One of the very first things that happens after the Fullcalendar is initialized and rendered is that the initial view is rendered and `datesRender` is called.

I check to see if `window.history.state` is null and if so I use `window.history.replaceState` to set the default view state.  I then either use `replaceState` or `pushState` to add or update the state info.

```
    'datesRender': function (info) {
        if (window.history.state === null) {
            //
            // seems like when a page is first visited the history
            // for that page has a null state.  Add a default state.
            const tempState = {
                'view': info.view.type,
                'range': {
                    'start': moment(info.view.activeStart)
                        .local().format(dateFormatHuman),
                    'end': moment(info.view.activeEnd)
                        .local().format(dateFormatHuman)
                },
                'url': window.location.href,
                'comment': "INIT"
            };

            window.history.replaceState(
                tempState,
                "INIT",
                window.location.href
            );
        } else {
            //
            // if state.comment = POP then we are here after a
            // BACK button press.  Change the comment to "dateRender".
            if (window.history.state.comment === "POP") {
                const tempState = window.history.state;
                tempState.comment = "datesRender";

                window.history.replaceState(
                    tempState,
                    "From pop",
                    window.location.href
                );
            } else {
                //
                // there is current state and we need to change views.
                // add new state for the new view
                const state = {
                    'view': info.view.type,
                    'range': {
                        'start': moment(info.view.activeStart)
                            .local().format(dateFormatHuman),
                        'end': moment(info.view.activeEnd)
                            .local().format(dateFormatHuman)
                    },
                    'url': window.location.href,
                    'comment': "datesRender"
                };

                window.history.pushState(
                    state,
                    "datesRender",
                    window.location.href
                );
            }
        }
    },
```

When the browser forward/back buttons are pressed the `window.onpopstate` event is triggered.  When the handler is run the "current" `window.history.state` is the state after the browser button POP.  I update the state comment to flag this as a browser button event then call the Fullcalendar `changeView` method to update the view.

```
    function handleStatePopEvent(event) {
        try {
            const tempState = window.history.state;
            tempState.comment = "POP";

            window.history.replaceState(
                tempState,
                tempState.comment,
                tempState.url
            );

            calendar.changeView(
                window.history.state.view,
                window.history.state.range
            );
        } catch (e) {
            throw `handleStatePopEvent: ${e.message}`;
        }
    }
```

The problem seems to be that after a Fullcalendar `prev` button click something changes in the FC internal state -- though I can't prove that.  The `window.history.state` is changed correctly in the `datesRender`.  When the browser back button is hit, the `window.onpopstate` event is triggered and the view and date ranges are correct to return to the previous month view but the `changeView` call renders nothing.

I have used my browser's Developer Tools debugger and have stepped all the way through `changeView` in this case.  Nothing dramatic jumps out at me other than at some point there is a flag that seems to say "Do I need to render anything?" is set to `false`.

Am I doing something wrong?